# VBA replacing ALL placeholders in Outlook html template with userform textbox and combobox

Tags: vba, replace, outlook, userform, placeholder

I'm not a programmer, but I like to create little macros for saving time on iterative tasks. Right now I was trying to create an userform able to replace on an HTML template few placeholders.

The code I've made so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\path\ciccio.oft")
  
    With OutMail
        .To = TextBox4.Text
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
              
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "###PLACEHOLDER1###", TextBox1.Text)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "###PLACEHOLDER2###", ComboBox1.Text)

        Unload UserForm2
        .Display
    End With
   
    Set OutMail = Nothing
  Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This works good on a plain text body, but on the HTML body just refuses to replace all ..
and seems even a little random.. so something is replaced and the rest not.

Any help?

Comment: In rare circumstances it is useful but when you see code with `On Error Resume Next` just before `With OutMail` **delete** `On Error Resume Next` before using it. Edit the question so it becomes more feasible for potential responders to attempt to answer. As is, it is almost the same as no code at all. If you see an error add it to the question.

Comment: thanks, followed your suggestion deleting the resuming on error, the fact still the same. I get replaced few placeholders ( the same as before) not all.

Comment: Cannot recreate on a template with text only.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The issue is in how is formatted the html body. I've edited the placeholder words in other file and then copy directly on the template, saving it.